# 1955 in Otro poema de los dones by Jorge Luis Borges

Tags: poetry, historical-context, spanish-language, jorge-luis-borges

In the poem [Otro poema de los dones](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/dones.html) by Jorge Luis Borges, there is a line which refers to 1955. Is Borges, being Argentine, referring to the military coup to unseat President Juan Perón of Argentina? Or what is the reference?

Original line in Spanish:

> Por ciertas vísperas y días de 1955,

English translation:

> For certain eves and days of 1955,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it is indeed a historical reference. The [year 1955](https://www.borges.pitt.edu/bibliography/1955-1) was double relevant to Borges:

1. He had been an anti-Peronist [1], so he welcomed the [Revolución Libertadora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revoluci%C3%B3n_Libertadora) of 16 September 1955. In fact, the [Wikipedia about Borges notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Luis_Borges#Anti-Peronism):

> According to [Borges biographer] Williamson, Borges shouted, "Viva la Patria", until his voice grew hoarse. [2]

2. After the "Revolución Libertadora", Borges was named director of the National Library [3] and he stayed in this position until the return and re-election of Juan Perón, when Borges resigned from his post. [4] [5]

---

References:

- [1] Tomas, Maximiliano: [Jorge Luis Borges: las razones de un antiperonismo feroz](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/cultura/jorge-luis-borges-razones-antiperonismo-feroz-nid2437640/), *La Nacion*, 02.09.2020.
- [2] Williamson, Edwin: *Borges: A Life*. New York: Viking, 2004.
- [3] Baldertson, Daniel: [1955](https://www.borges.pitt.edu/bibliography/1955-1). Borges Center, University of Pittsburgh.
- [4] Baldertson, Daniel: [1973](https://www.borges.pitt.edu/bibliography/1973-1). Borges Center, University of Pittsburgh.
- [5] Borges, Jorge Luis: [*The Last Interview: and Other Conversations*](https://books.google.de/books?id=68R9VS3WHPwC&pg=PT139&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). Melville House, 2013.

Comment: I agree that it's a historical reference. I doubt the "double" list is on spot. It's just the first fact what matters here, the second one is rather a corolary (among many others).

Comment: @leonbloy Do you disagree with the statement "The year 1955 was double relevant to Borges"? Or what are you disagreeing with?